# How to set dynamic slides width in Glide.js

Tags: javascript, glidejs

Surprisingly I couldn't find an option for such banal thing. I'm trying to build a slider of  that have dynamic content inside. So they have dynamic widths.

How can I tell Glide not to assign a fixed identical to the slides but instead to preserve their native width?

here my example: codepen.io/rolfo85/pen/GRpqdNZ

I need something like the OWL carusel auto-width
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This will be doable with `width: auto;`. But to make sure of that we should see your codes first.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rolfo85/pen/GRpqdNZ actually my problem is bigger. I have 10 elements in total and I want to see them all on a large screens. Then when I resize the page, I want to gradually hide them so I can start sliding them. On top of this, the width should be auto calculated. trying to build something that has this behaviour: https://uxdesign.cc/creating-horizontal-scrolling-containers-the-right-way-css-grid-c256f64fc585